# Array Subtract From JSon Object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Json Object array

```
   posturlContent = [
        { "Title": "Bbc news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test BBC </div>", "Uri": "http://bbc.co.uk" },
        { "Title": "CNN news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test CNN</div>", "Uri": "http://cnn.com" },
        { "Title": "Youtube news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test Youtube </div>", "Uri": "http://youtube.com" },
    ];
```

I have a JS array

```
uris =["http://cnn.com", "http://abcnews.com",...]
```

I need an Output of posturlContent only of items that are in uris hence below.

```
   posturlContent = [

        { "Title": "CNN news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test CNN</div>", "Uri": "http://cnn.com" }

    ];
```

I tried using this but getting back empty posturlContent

```
    $.each(uris, function(){
        var siteUrl = this.valueOf();
        posturlContent = $.grep(posturlContent, function(item){
            return item.Uri.toLowerCase() != siteUrl.toLowerCase();
        });
    })
```

Comment: Remove the last comma from your `posturlContent` object (after the last brace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use an inverse logic, looping `posturlContent` with `$.grep`, and checking `uris` with `indexOf`:

```
posturlContent = $.grep(posturlContent, function(item){
    return uris.indexOf(item.Uri) > -1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExBsa/

Note: to support Array.indexOf in IE <= 8, use the [mdn polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility), or simply jQuery's $.inArray as suggested by vher2.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var tmp = [];
$.each(posturlContent, function(){
    if ($.inArray(this.Uri, uris) !== -1) {
        tmp.push(this);
    }
});
posturlContent = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.each()` loop is buggy since you are modifying `posturlContent` inside the loop, in the second iteration `posturlContent` will be empty.

```
var original = posturlContent;
posturlContent = [];
$.each(uris, function(i, siteUrl) {
    posturlContent = posturlContent.concat($.grep(original, function(item) {
        return item.Uri.toLowerCase() == siteUrl.toLowerCase();
    }));
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mTJnH/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var posturlContent = [
                      {"Title": "Bbc news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test BBC </div>", "Uri": "http://bbc.co.uk" },
                      { "Title": "CNN news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test CNN</div>", "Uri": "http://cnn.com" },
                      { "Title": "Youtube news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test Youtube </div>", "Uri": "http://youtube.com" },
                     ];

    var uris = ["http://cnn.com", "http://abcnews.com"]

    var outputArr = posturlContent.filter(function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<uris.length; i++) {
            return data.Uri == uris[i];
        }
    });
```